# Ayuda para hacer un páginado en PHP

Tags: php, mysql, html5

quiero mostrar 9 imágenes por página y que aparezca un link para ir a la siguiente, algo así como en algunas páginas de video que si quieres ver más aparece anterior<>siguiente. Espero y me entiendan.
El código en el cual me estoy apoyando es el siguiente

```html
 <?php
 include('conexion.php');
 //Cantidad de Registros
 $porPagina = 9;
 if (isset($_GET['pagina'])){
  $pagina = $_GET['pagina'];
 }else{
  $pagina = 1;}
  //La variable empieza en 0 y se multiplica $porPagina
  $empieza =($pagina = 1) * $porPagina;
  //Hacemos la consulta con LIMIT
 $query = "SELECT * FROM imagenes LIMIT $empieza, $porPagina";
 $resultado = $conexion->query($query);
   ?>
```

Aquí muestro las imagenes

```html
<div class="imagenes">
    <ul class="productos">
        <?php while($row = $resultado->fetch_assoc()){ ?>
            <li class="imagenes">
                <b><?php echo $row['nombre'];?></b> </br>
                <div class="caption-img-product" style="background-image:url('./<?php echo $row['ruta_imagen']; ?>');" ></div>
                <p><?php echo$row['descripcion'];?></p>
            </li>
        <?php } ?>
    </ul>
</div>
    
</div>
<div>
```

Y en este me genera error de sintaxis los echo y el for

```html
<div><?php
//Seleccionamos todo de la tabla imagenes
$query = "SELECT * FROM imagenes";
$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion,$query);

//Contar el total de registros
$total_registros = mysqli_num_rows($resultado);

//Usansando ceil para dividir el total de registros entre $porPagina.
$total_paginas = ceil($total_registros * $porPagina)
//Link a Primera página
echo "<a href='productos.php?pagina=1'>".'Primera '."</a>";
for($i=1; $i<=$total_paginas, $i++){
 echo "<a href='productos.php?pagina=".$i."'>".$i."</a>";
 https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask#//link de la ultima pagina
 echo "<a href='productos.php?pagina=$total_paginas'>."'Última '."</a>";

?>
</div>
```

No se me da bien concatenar xD. Omitiendo el último bloque de código solo me aparecen 6 imágenes. 
Si pueden ayudarme con la sintaxis de los echo y for y si la forma de querer realizar el páginado es correcta

Comment: arriba del `echo` te falta un `;` en **$total_paginas**, después puedes utilizar un `sprintf` si se te da mucho la onda de concatenar

Comment: gracias, eso soluciona el error del primer echo, no me di cuenta,

Comment: el ultimo `echo` que tienes dentro del for, antes de este, hay una línea de un link... Comentala con  `//` o `/**/`

Comment: ese https:// aparecio de la nada, raios

Comment: Teneís algún otro error o ya funca tu código?

Comment: tengo error en el for y en el segundo echo despues del for

Comment: Yo lo pondría de la siguiente manera : `echo sprintf("<a href='productos.php?pagina=%s'>%s</a>"); ` o dejarlo normal, al utilizar doble comilla puedes imprimir las variables directamente sin necesidad de concatenar nada, es decir, `echo "<a href='productos.php?pagina=$i'>$i</a>";` según yo no tendría problema

Comment: el que me da problemas es echo "<a href='productos.php?pagina=$total_paginas'>."'Última '."</a>"; y el for no se por que?  for($i=1; $i<=$total_paginas, $i++){

Comment: Es problema es que dentro del **for** van puros `;` tienes `,`, y de tu echo, esta mal concatenado  `"<a href='productos.php?pagina=$total_paginas'>Última</a>"` sin concatenar la palabra, ya que lo maneja el echo como un string

Comment: gracias bro, ya no hay errores, solo que la pagina me muestra 6 y no nueven registros, ademas de que me aperecen debajo los a href pero se van hasta 135 y no me muestra las demas imagenes, me redirige a las mismas